# How to create a Navigatable Tree View Menu in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to create **a Navigatable Tree View** in an **MVC 3 project.** This treeview has to be generated from the database. 
There will be 3-5 levels for this tree and the final node of the tree view will be "Insert Your Comment". 
When the user clicks **on the final node** - "Insert Your Comment" (there can be more than one final node), **the control should open a new comments page** where
the user can **add his/her comment**. Has anyone got any idea about doing this?
I am using MVC3 (Razor).
Thanks,

Comment: have you thought about building up the tags in a helper on the server side and then rendering them in the razor view as a helper? done this before with a menu which can work nicely. I can provide a link to a code sample if you wish.

Comment: Hi Hazelton,Would it be possible for you to share your code? It will be really helpful. Many thanks